# File copy using vbs through unknown directory to known directory

Tags: vbscript, wildcards

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("c:\temp\abc\123.xml") 
objFile.Copy "c:\programdata\ABC\DEF\XXXXXX\JKL\"
```

I need to move *123.xml* to the *\JKL* directory but `XXXXXX` could be any directory name (unknown to me) on the 100 target PCs this script will be run.

How can I wildcard this directory name or get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i doubt it.

but you can actually work around it.

1)populate the contents of folder c:\programdata\ABC\DEF\
2)check each subdirectory under c:\programdata\ABC\DEF\ for a folder under the name JKL
3) when u find the directory JKL, use the FSO object path from here to copy your file.

this should work...